# ASP.NET Object reference not set to an instance of an object after deploying in IIS8 - null exception in group roles editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

After deploying our solution on iis8 we have got a problem due to editing GroupAdmin or User.
the problem occurs whenever we are trying to edit a user or a group roles. When in local testing there is no error. After debugging the problem remotely from the deployed version, we see that there is a problem when connecting to the database context. returns "Reference null ".
is there any further configurations in the IIS or in the SQL database? any permissions? 
Please help me. I can't seem to find any other similar problem.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" related to roles

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5xE5.jpg)

Comment: Could you please share which line throw null reference error? It seems your application could connect to the identity database but the table doesn't contain the related data.

Comment: In ApplicationGroupManager  class where :

  public ApplicationGroupManager()
        {

            _db = HttpContext.Current
                .GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();   //this return NULL Exception whenever I try to edit a group role
          

The problem is that it could load the list of groups and roles but it stopps when editing any of these group roles

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved. It is related to the targetFramework that should be 4.5.1 and not 4.0.

Thanks.